# How can I do a string comparison in a Handlebars.Net template?

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I am trying to use a Handlebars.Net template to iterate over a list of string and to render either one thing or the other based on the value of the string.

This is a cut-down example of what I am trying to achieve. I have an object with a list of string property, and a template that loops through the list and renders some HTML based on the value of the string:

Simple object with list:

```
public class Box
{
   public List<string> BoxItems { get; set; }
}
```

Simple template to iterate over the list and render one thing or the other:

```
{{#each Box.BoxItems }}
    {{#if this == "item" }}
        <p>This is a box item</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>This is not a box item</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I have tried registering my own helper but haven't managed to make this work.

How can I can get this to work using the Handlebars.Net port (not the HandlebarsJS version)?

EDIT:

The helper I tried using that doesn't work is this:

```
handlebars.RegisterHelper("eq_test", (a, b) => a.ToString().Equals(b.ToString()));
```

and it is used in the template like this:

```
{{#each Box.BoxItems }}
    {{#if (eq_test this "item") }}
        <p>This is a box item</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>This is not a box item</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question,

I registered the helper like this:

```
handlebars.RegisterHelper("isEq", (ctx, args) => {
    if (args.Length != 2)
    {
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    
    string str1 = args[0].ToString();
    string str2 = args[1].ToString();

    return str1 == str2;
});
```

And then I used it in the template like this:

```
{{#each Box.BoxItems }}
   {{#if (isEq this item) }}
      <p>This is a box item</p>
   {{else}}
      <p>This is not a box item</p>
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Obviously this is not a perfect example of how to do this. There is no real checking done on the parameters and it is clearly a string comparison.

But hopefully it will save somebody a few hours of figuring out how to register a simple equality check helper for Handlebars.Net.

Comment: you may want to see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269178/handlebars-net-if-condition-helper